# Strength of association test with binary variables

Tags: r, categorical-data, binary-data, effect-size, descriptive-statistics

I have a dataset with different purchases for two different items from the same users. So the users purchased the two items at different points in time. I also have 3 different variables: `High`, `Mid`, and `Low` twice (Low, Mid,High for each product) within this dataset. So the product are broken up into these categories. For example, suppose I bought item X and its classified as a High price item. I then want to see if the same user bought an item Y at the same classification level (High). My end goal is to see if there is an association of a customer buying items at the same classification level across different items.

My first thought was to use a Chi square test but I am not sure this is the best way to do it. 
I am doing this in R. All of the data are binary variables. Here is an example of what the dataset looks like.

```
User      Type             High  Mid  Low        
1         Product 1        0     1    0       
1         Product 2        1     0    0       
2         Product 1        0     1    0
2         Product 2        0     1    0
3         Product 1        0     0    1
3         Product 2        0     1    0
```

Comment: Are your datasets paired observations? E.g., is one object being rated `High/Mid/Low` by two raters for whom you're interested in quantifying agreement?

Comment: The dataset are tier leves of purchases. So trying to see if the same person are buying items in each tier level. So the data was merged on an indiv_id who had purchases in both categories. I am trying to see if there is a relationship between the levels. For example, if they buy a Mid tier item in one level does that mean that they are are likely to buy an item in the Mid tier for another product. Sorry for the confusion

Comment: I'm afraid confusion is bound to occur in matters of statistics. Your continuing efforts to clarify are most appreciated and unfortunately rare in our population of new users! We'll get to the bottom of this yet – I'll mull it over, keep an eye on answers, and offer my own if I have anything to add in the end.

Comment: You seem to have an important choice to make: do you want to consider `User` 1's purchases of `Product`s 1 and 2 more similar than the purchases of a `User` who selects one `Product` from the `High` price category and one from the `Low` category? BTW, if so, and if you have actual prices for the `Product`s, it would be wise to use those instead of trichotomizing the price data. If you prefer not to consider `Product`s of `High` price more similar to `Mid` than `Low`, you'd want to treat your price data as [tag:nominal], not [tag:ordinal]. Your choice will greatly affect what results you'll get

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure association is what you're trying to answer here? Is it possible that you might be interested in interrater agreement?

At any rate, there are two approaches to handling these data: one in which frequencies are treated as unordered (suboptimal) and the other in which you borrow information across trends (low/mid/high immediately suggests an ordinal nature to these data). The plain-vanilla approach to option 1 is to create a $3 \times 3$ contingency table of frequencies and conduct a Pearson $\chi^2$ test of independence with 4 degrees of freedom. The test statistic is the squared differences between observed and expected values based on marginal frequencies of tabular data. The R syntax would be `chisq.test(table(dat$rate1, dat$rate2))`.

Alternately, for approach number 2, there have been several methods proposed to analyze such data. A perfectly valid test of association for this circumstance is a simple linear regression model treating ordinal values as numeric quantities: 0:low, 1:mid, 2:high and regressing the rate2 variable upon rate1 (or vice versa, depending on the nature of the quesiton). R syntax would require casting these variables to numeric `lm(as.numeric(rate2) ~ as.numeric(rate1))` ensuring that `levels(rate1) == levels(rate2)` and `levels(rate1) == c('low', 'mid', 'high')`.

Comment: Wouldn't your option 1 test associations among `low, mid, high` within a single (or the combined) dataset? What if these are unordered, and the overall association between frequencies of each across datasets is desired?  That's how I understood the OP...but I'm suspicious of treating these variables as unordered too. As for that option 2, wouldn't a rank correlation like Kendall's $\tau$ be *more perfectly* valid?

Comment: @NickStauner OP mentioned that the results come from merged data, so there should be a 1-1 correspondence between observations. However, the question as stated does not suggest that these data are paired outcome data, but more a traditional predictor/outcome relationship. I too was confused, which is why I prefaced my answer with a nod to agreement as a possible secondary measure. In that case, a kappa or weighted kappa would be preferable. Personally, I disagree rank statistics methods, I think their hypotheses are difficult to state and are often of less power than traditional tests.

Comment: @user3120266 Can you restate your first sentence? I'm lost.

Comment: the merge is on another id variable that they share. This is based on item classification of customers who bought the same item. For example, looking to find the strength of association that items on mid tiers correspond with items on other tiers.

Comment: @user3120266 what you claim to want measure makes little sense to me. Are you trying to infer whether, given a product has an average rating of $p$ (based on 0/1/2 codes) that the distribution of ratings are homogeneous among products with similar ratings? Do you have exactly two ratings on each product (n=1700)? Or are you aggregating a number of possible ratings together for products to find the "average rating"?

Comment: This is data based on user who have bought the same item. I am trying to see if a customer who bought an item in a Mid tier (a binary variable) also bought a different product in a Mid tier (another binary variable). There are three different tiers that you can be placed in for your purchases (Low, High, Mid).

Comment: @user3120266 this is all pretty unclear. I recommend you make substantial revisions to the question as the comments section isn't the appropriate place to flesh out such issues.

Comment: @AdamO I agree. I have updated the OP with revisions.